# HYbridauth for facebook login doesn't work

Tags: hybridauth

I was trying to configure the hybridauth library so that I can use the the google + and the facebook sign in. But it keeps me giving a fatal error:

```
 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Facebook\Facebook.php' (include_path='.:/var/www/magilla/lib:/var/www/magilla/models') in /var/www/magilla/lib/RPC/Util.php on line 168
```

> I followed each and every step of their documentation. I have used the
>   composer to install the library. The library version is 2.9 and the
>   facebook graph sdk, the most recent version of github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**READ EDIT*2 for a proper solution instead**

I am encountering the same issue and I suppose you install hybridauth the same way as I did, which is running `composer require hybridauth/hybridauth` on your project root folder.

> I solved this by running `composer install` within the hybridauth
>   directory where its composer.json exist, that will install facebook
>   sdk within the hybridauth directory where the autoload.php is being
>   load by the script (I personally feel like it is more like a hack than
>   a proper solution... but I have a feeling that the hybridauth
>   developer expect you to clone then run the composer install instead of
>   composer requiring it...I maybe wrong as I just start using composer
>   as well)

*EDIT [check out the issue on their github](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/779), there is a bug where the vendor path is being replaced by one in their code, it also mention it is being fixed in later commit. I am new to composer as well so I don't know how to specific the commit for it to update to... if you know how to do it let me know as well

*EDIT*2 alright, I updated to 2.9.3-dev and it seems to solve the issue without generating any new one, I also use that for google and twitter and those are fine too. To update, edit your composer.json to this

```
"require": {
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "^2.9-dev"
    }
```

then run `composer update` on your command prompt, things should work as long as you require the composer autoload.php for your script